# Meu programa dá erro quando o valor do array é null

Tags: java, json

Tenho um programa que retira relatórios de um sistema, estou incluindo mais uma tabela no programa.
Os dados que são lidos, vem de um *array* mas as vezes ele está vazio, e quando dá isso o programa dá erro.

Coloquei um if para verificar se a variável está `null`, pois se estiver ele pegará o valor de outra tabela.

Mas quando debuguei ele acusou erro:

> Source not found

```
JSONObject js2 = js.getJSONObject("cliente").getJSONArray("enderecoList").getJSONObject(0);
```

nessa linha e o programa para de rodar.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject js = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject js2 = js.getJSONObject("cliente").getJSONArray("enderecoList").getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject js3;
                if (js2 == null){
                    js3 = js.getJSONObject("unidade").getJSONObject("municipio");
                } else {
                    js3 = js2.getJSONObject("municipio");
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde, você pode usar a propriedade `has` para validar se o existe o atributo dentro do json.

Segue:

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject js = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject js3;

            if (js.has("unidade")) {
                JSONObject unidadeJson = js.getJSONObject("unidade");
                if (unidadeJson.has("municipio")) {
                    js3 = unidadeJson.getJSONObject("municipio");
                }
            }

            if (js.has("cliente")) {
                JSONObject jsonClient = js.getJSONObject("cliente");
                if (jsonClient.has("enderecoList") && !jsonClient.isNull("enderecoList")) {
                    JSONArray enderecoArray = jsonClient.getJSONArray("enderecoList");
                    if (enderecoArray.length() > 0) {
                        JSONObject js2 = enderecoArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        if (js2.has("municipio")) {
                            js3 = js2.getJSONObject("municipio");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se poderá ser isso mas existe um método próprio do JSON para verificar se o valor está a NULL. O método é o isNull();

Por exemplo:

```
if(jsonObject.isNull("parentId")){
   jsonObject.put("parentId", 0);
}
```

Comment: Tentei utilizar o metodo, mas ele aponta que é incompativel e que é necessario uma variavel do tipo String.